# MVC4 Unit test NSubstitute Could not find a call to return from

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, unit-testing, nsubstitute

I have a MVC4 web application I'm unit testing right now. It uses entity framework for the database portion. I'm using NSubstitute to mock the database. This code is basically copied and pasted from another site which works fine, so I hope I'm just missing something super simple.

Thanks in advance!

Applications table in SQL:

```
AppID   | ApplicationName
----------------------------
1       | MyCoolApplication
2       | MyOtherApplication
```

Entity created the Application class:

```
public class Application
{
    public int AppID { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
}
```

The mock section of the unit test looks like this:

```
var mockDb = Substitute.For<MyCoolApplicationsEntities>();

var applications = new List<Application>
{
    new Application {AppID = 1, ApplicationName = "MyCoolApplication"},
    new Application {AppID = 2, ApplicationName = "MyOtherApplication"},
};

var mockApplicationSet = Substitute.For<IDbSet<Application>, DbSet<Application>>();
mockApplicationSet.Provider.Returns(applications.AsQueryable().Provider);
mockApplicationSet.Expression.Returns(applications.AsQueryable().Expression);
mockApplicationSet.ElementType.Returns(applications.AsQueryable().ElementType);
mockApplicationSet.GetEnumerator().Returns(applications.AsQueryable().GetEnumerator());

mockApplicationSet.When(q => q.Add(Arg.Any<Application>()))
    .Do(q => applications.Add(q.Arg<Application>()));

mockApplicationSet.When(q => q.Remove(Arg.Any<Application>()))
    .Do(q => applications.Remove(q.Arg<Application>()));


mockDb.Applications.Returns(mockApplicationSet); //This is the line creating the error
```

The full error is:

> Test method
>   MyProjectName.Controllers.MyControllerTest.TestOfSectionImTesting
>   threw exception: 
>   NSubstitute.Exceptions.CouldNotSetReturnDueToNoLastCallException:
>   Could not find a call to return from.
>
> Make sure you called Returns() after calling your substitute (for
>   example: mySub.SomeMethod().Returns(value)), and that you are not
>   configuring other substitutes within Returns() (for example, avoid
>   this: mySub.SomeMethod().Returns(ConfigOtherSub())).
>
> If you substituted for a class rather than an interface, check that
>   the call to your substitute was on a virtual/abstract member. Return
>   values cannot be configured for non-virtual/non-abstract members.
>
> Correct use:
>
> ```
> mySub.SomeMethod().Returns(returnValue);
> ```
>
> Potentially problematic use:
>
> ```
> mySub.SomeMethod().Returns(ConfigOtherSub());
> ```
>
> Instead try:
>
> ```
> var returnValue = ConfigOtherSub(); 
>
> mySub.SomeMethod().Returns(returnValue);
> ```

But that doesn't work in my environment because Applications isn't a method. Like I said, this works fine in another site of mine, so it's got to be something basic I'm missing. Nothing I've found online has been helpful with my particular case. I updated to the newest version of NSubstitute and I uninstalled/reinstalled, but still have got nothing.

Again, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what ended up working:

```
var context = Substitute.For<MyCoolApplicationsEntities>();

var applications = new List<Application>
{
    new Application {AppID = 1, ApplicationName = "MyCoolApplication"}
};

var mockApplications = Substitute.For<DbSet<Application>, IQueryable<Application>>();
((IQueryable<Application>)mockApplications).Provider.Returns(applications.AsQueryable().Provider);
((IQueryable<Application>)mockApplications).Expression.Returns(applications.AsQueryable().Expression);
((IQueryable<Application>)mockApplications).ElementType.Returns(applications.AsQueryable().ElementType);
((IQueryable<Application>)mockApplications).GetEnumerator().Returns(applications.AsQueryable().GetEnumerator());

mockApplications.When(q => q.Add(Arg.Any<Application>()))
    .Do(q => applications.Add(q.Arg<Application>()));

mockApplications.When(q => q.Remove(Arg.Any<Application>()))
    .Do(q => applications.Remove(q.Arg<Application>()));

context.Applications = mockApplications;
```

Answer (score 15):

NSubstitute can not mock non-virtual members. (There are [quite a few caveats to substituting for classes](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/creating-a-substitute/).)

`MyCoolApplicationsEntities.Applications` will need to be virtual for `.Returns()` to work.

Comment: David, thanks for looking at this. I was able to get it working with the help of a coworker this morning. Please see my answer if you'd like. Thanks again!

Comment: @Timothy, glad you got it sorted! So the prob was not going through the IQueryable interface? That means `context.Applications.Returns(mockApplications)` should work correctly now?

Comment: context.Applications.Returns(mockApplications) still shoots the same error. context.Applications = mockApplications works now though.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see you classes but you need to create interfaces with virtual members and have your code call the class by the interface, then you will be able to mock out the class.